# Can not find control with unspecified name attribute Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, controls, name-attribute

I'm facing the the following error.

[image]

And when I click at the line pointed with **BLUE ARROW** in the above image, it points to `of` of `ngFor loop` in my html template.

```
     <div class="w-[60%]">
       <select
        name="duration"
        id=""
        class="text-[1rem] leading-6 py-2 px-8 border border-[#BCBCBC] w-[27.875rem] rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:border-primary"
        [formControl]="demoLength"
        required
      >
        <option
          [value]="timing.value"
          *ngFor="let timing of staticDurationArray"
          selected="{{ timing.selected }}"
        >
          {{ timing.time }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

**And in the above code the `staticDurationArray` is an array with static data in TS file**

```
staticDurationArray = [
    {
      time: '15 min',
      value: 15,
      selected: '',
    },
    {
      time: '30 min',
      value: 30,
      selected: '',
    },
    {
      time: '45 min',
      value: 45,
      selected: '',
    },
    {
      time: '1 hr',
      value: 60,
      selected: '',
    },
]
```

Comment: Are you getting this error when submitting the form or during initial rendering? Can you also include the code where the form is defined (and bound to some variable)?

Comment: Error is clearly related to forms. Where is your form? Can you provide code that contains form?

Comment: First it is showing when rendering. Second are you talking about html form?

Comment: Do you need to see my `ngOnInit` as well?.I'm updating my code with my entire form.It is very large form btw.

Comment: I have updated the code you can chexk,And tell me If you want something else as well.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer I tried by putting an `*ngIf` condition to my piece of code and the issue is solved

```
<div class="w-[60%]">
              <select
                *ngIf="demoLength"
                [formControl]="demoLength"
                name="duration"
                id=""
                class="text-[1rem] leading-6 py-2 px-8 border border-[#BCBCBC] w-[27.875rem] rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:border-primary"
                required
              >
                <option
                  [value]="timing.value"
                  *ngFor="let timing of staticDurationArray"
                  selected="{{ timing.selected }}"
                >
                  {{ timing.time }}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
```